# What's the value of cos(x) that verifies the following equality

Tags: trigonometry

The equality is:

$\ 2 \sin^2  2x - 2\sin x \sin 3x = 4 \cos x + \cos 2x $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use that $$\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$
$$\cos(2x)=\cos^2(x)-\sin(x)^2$$
$$\sin(3x)=4\sin(x)\cos^2(x)-\sin(x)$$
So you will get
$$2(1-\cos^2(x))-4\cos(x)-2\cos^2(x)+1=0$$ and let $$t=\cos(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint

$$4\cos x+\cos2x=1-\cos4x-(\cos2x-\cos4x)$$

Now replace $\cos2x$ with $2\cos^2x-1$ to form a quadratic equation in $\cos x$

Used http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html